# $(window).load(function () not working

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to figure out why the `load function` on a page is not working properly I have put in a simple alert to test whether the it is firing. I get nothing. Can anyone explain why? Such an alert works in other javascript functions on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () 
{
window.alert("Hello");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included JQuery?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no pending HTTP requests? Especially third party images, scripts...

Comment: If you change the alert to `console.log("hello");` does it show up? If yes, you have a pop up block installed that may be blocking alert()

Comment: @Vucko added and it now works. Thanks. Add as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need `jQuery` in order to ONLY specify script to run on page load.
 
**Without including jQuery**, you only need to write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () 
{
window.alert("Hello");
};
</script>
```

This is pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well. The thing is First of all you have to know that your using a method which is in the java-script library called jQuery.

1. So if you have no added jQuery library the method will not work.
2. If there is any error before the JS code that your trying, the code will never execute until you fix the first error.

Try to use a tool like firebug which can be installed to the Firefox as an add-on and turn it on. you can debug using that tool where the code gets fail.

I have attached an screen shot that shows the unrecognized jQuery methods error, with not including the jQuery library.

[image]